# Spark 2.3 submit on Kubernetes error

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Getting below errors when I’m trying to run spark-submit on k8 cluster

**Error 1**: This looks like a warning it doesn’t interrupt the app running inside executor pod but keeps on getting this warning

```
2018-03-09 11:15:21 WARN  WatchConnectionManager:192 - Exec Failure
java.io.EOFException
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByte(RealBufferedSource.java:73)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readHeader(WebSocketReader.java:113)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame(WebSocketReader.java:97)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.loopReader(RealWebSocket.java:262)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:201)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Error2**: This is intermittent error  which is failing the executor pod to run

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2747)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.spark.core.QuantumSession$.initialize(QuantumSession.scala:62)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.spark.core.QuantumSession$.getSparkSession(QuantumSession.scala:80)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.workflow.WorkflowApp$.getSession(WorkflowApp.scala:116)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.workflow.WorkflowApp$.main(WorkflowApp.scala:90)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.workflow.WorkflowApp.main(WorkflowApp.scala)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [myapp-ef79db3d9f4831bf85bda14145fdf113-driver-driver]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:62)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:71)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:228)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend.<init>(KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2741)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Try again
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:137)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:171)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:377)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:343)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:312)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:295)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:783)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:217)
    ... 15 more
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@5f59185e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Stopped Spark web UI at http://myapp-ef79db3d9f4831bf85bda14145fdf113-driver-svc.default.svc:4040
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2018-03-09 15:00:39 WARN  MetricsSystem:66 - Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2747)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.spark.core.QuantumSession$.initialize(QuantumSession.scala:62)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.spark.core.QuantumSession$.getSparkSession(QuantumSession.scala:80)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.workflow.WorkflowApp$.getSession(WorkflowApp.scala:116)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.workflow.WorkflowApp$.main(WorkflowApp.scala:90)
    at com.capitalone.quantum.workflow.WorkflowApp.main(WorkflowApp.scala)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [myapp-ef79db3d9f4831bf85bda14145fdf113-driver]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:62)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:71)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:228)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend.<init>(KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2741)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Try again
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:137)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:171)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:377)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:343)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:312)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:295)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:783)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:217)
    ... 15 more
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-03-09 15:00:39 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5bd85c96-d689-4c53-a0b3-1eadd32357cb
```

Note:Able to run the application successfully but spark-submit run fails  with above error2 very frequently.

Comment: Same error here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152771/kubernetes-1-9-cant-initialize-sparkcontext Tested with both SparkPi and custom app.

Comment: It's a dns lookup failure, probably due to too many lookups? Do you have a DNS cache there so lookups do not go to the DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `${SPARK_LOCAL_IP}` environment variable to pod IP and pass to spark-submit this environment variable using `--conf spark.driver.host=${SPARK_LOCAL_IP}`.

See the spark docs for more information regarding these variables.

Comment: you may also need to create a service in k8s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655476/spark-k8s-how-to-run-spark-submit-on-kubernetes-with-client-mode

Answer (score 0):

My ubuntu18.04 PC also encountered this problem, but it has been resolved. The general steps are as follows:

1. Get the url through the `minikube dashboard -url` and enter the dashboard. Search for the coredns service to start normally
2. Check if the coredns service log is caused by `Loop ... detected ...`
3. If this problem is caused, vim /etc/resolv.conf,
   Modify nameserver 127.0.0.53 to nameserver 8.8.8.8.
4. restart `minikube stop && minikube start`

If coredns can't be started, you can check it out here: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/loop