# Spark/k8s: How to run spark submit on Kubernetes with client mode

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to use `spark-submit` with `client` mode in the kubernetes pod to submit jobs to EMR (Due to some other infra issues, we don't allow `cluster` mode). 
By default, `spark-submit` uses the `hostname` of the pod as the `spark.driver.host` and the `hostname` is the pod's hostname so `spark executor` could not resolve it. And the `spark.driver.port` is also locally to the pod (container).

I know a way to pass some confs to `spark-submit` so that the `spark executor` can talk to the `driver`, those configs are:

`--conf spark.driver.bindAddress=0.0.0.0 --conf spark.driver.host=$HOST_IP_OF_K8S_WORKER --conf spark.driver.port=32000 --conf spark.driver.blockManager.port=32001`

and create a service to in the kubernetes so that `spark executor` can talk to the `driver`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spark-block-manager
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: port-0
      nodePort: 32000
      port: 32000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 32000
    - name: port-1
      nodePort: 32001
      port: 32001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 32001
    - name: port-2
      nodePort: 32002
      port: 32002
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 32002
```

---

But the issue is there are can be more than 1 pods running on one k8s worker and even more than 1 `spark-submit` jobs in one pod. So before launching a pod, we need to dynamically select few available ports in the k8s node and create a service to do the port mapping and then during launching the pod, pass those ports into the pod to tell `spark-submit` to use them. I feel like this is a little bit complex.

Using `hostNetwork: true` could potentially solve this issue but it introduces lots of other issues in our infra so this is not an option.

If `spark-submit` can support `bindPort` concept just like `driver.bindAddress` and `driver.host` or support `proxy`, it will be cleaner to solve the issue.

Does someone have similar situation? Please share some insights.

Thanks.

Additional context:
`spark version`: `2.4`

Comment: Or create a proxy pod running on each worker node to find available port and tight it to the pod that needs to run `spark-submit`

Comment: Doesn't EMR offer YARN for running Spark?

Comment: Can you use Livy API on EMR to submit jobs in cluster mode?

Comment: @cricket_007 it does. but we want the spark-client (majority of them are airflow workers) to live in k8s.

Comment: @AliaksandrSasnouskikh Due to some other infra issues, we don't allow cluster mode

Comment: Have you looked to VPC peering between EKS and EMR VPCs? This may lead you to a deep networking configs, but probably having it set up can give you the most beautiful solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark submit can take additional args like, `--conf spark.driver.bindAddress, --conf spark.driver.host, --conf spark.driver.port, --conf spark.driver.blockManager.port, --conf spark.port.maxRetries`. The `spark.driver.host` and `driver.port` is used to tell Spark Executor to use this host and port to connect back to the Spark submit.

We use `hostPort` and `containerPort` to expose the ports inside the container, inject the port range and `hostIP` as the environment variables to the Pod so that spark-submit knows what to use. So those additional args are:

```
--conf spark.driver.bindAddress=0.0.0.0` # has to be `0.0.0.0` so that it is accessible outside pod
--conf spark.driver.host=$HOST_IP # k8s worker ip, can be easily injected to the pod
--conf spark.driver.port=$SPARK_DRIVER_PORT # defined as environment variable
--conf spark.driver.blockManager.port=$SPARK_DRIVER_PORT # defined as environment variable
--conf spark.port.maxRetries=$SPARK_PORT_MAX_RETRIES # defined as environment variable
```

The `hostPort` is local to the Kubernetes worker, which means we don’t need to worry about the run out of ports. The k8s scheduler can find a host to run the pod.

We can reserve the ports from 40000 to 49000 on each host, and open 8 ports for each pod (as each spark-submit requires 2 open ports). The ports are chosen based on the pod_id. Since Kubernetes recommends running less than 100 pods per node, the ports collision will be very rare.

Comment: what is worse, the `NodePort` is on the cluster level, you can easily run out of ports.

Comment: I am looking for exactly same solution. I did try to open two ports on the spark notebook pod using a NodePort service but it still gives connection closed error. Please let me know if you have some working solution for it, I am stuck at last step for it.

Comment: the above solution worked for me. did you set the ` spark.driver.bindAddress=0.0.0.0`?